# Use Airflow for batch processing to dynamically start multiple tasks based on the output of a parent task

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to figure out if Airflow can be used to express a workflow where multiple instances of the same task need to be started based on the output of a parent task. Airflow supports multiple workers, so I naively expect that Airflow can be used to orchestrate workflows involving batch processing. So far I failed to find any recipe/direction that would fit this model. What is the right way to leverage Airflow for a bath processing workflow like the one below? Assume there is a pool of Airflow workers.

Example of a workflow:
1. Start Task A to produce multiple files
2. For each file start an instance of Task B (might be another workflow)
3. Wait for all instances of Task B, then start Task C

Comment: From what I know you can do: 1. Make a DAG with the task that creates files after each file created trigger dag B with params {filepath, last file bool}. 2. Process filepath, if last file true trigger dag C

Comment: @AndreyKartashov thank you! Did you happen by any chance to come across an example or multiple ones demonstrating activities involved in the workflow you've  described above?

Comment: There are two DAGs here: https://github.com/datirium/biowardrobe-airflow-analysis/blob/master/biowardrobe_airflow_analysis/biowardrobe/download.py - one is monitoring database and if data available triggers another one for each new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hack to parallelize processing of input data in Airflow, I use a custom operator that splits the input into a predetermined number of partitions. The downstream operator gets replicated for each partition and if needed the result can be merged again. For local files, the operator runs the `split` command. In Kubernetes, this works nicely with the cluster autoscaling.